Shopify GraphQL: Create a variant with an inventory quanitity of 999
I am creating variants for a Shopify product using productVariantsBulkCreate in the Shopify GraphQL API:
mutation productVariantsBulkCreate($productId: ID!, $variants: [ProductVariantsBulkInput!]!) {
  productVariantsBulkCreate(productId: $productId, strategy: REMOVE_STANDALONE_VARIANT, variants: $variants){
    (...)
  }
}

The input for the variants looks something like this:
{
    barcode: db_variant.barcode,
    compareAtPrice: db_variant.compareAtPrice?.toFixed(2) || undefined,
    inventoryItem: {
      cost: db_variant.costPerItem,
      harmonizedSystemCode: db_variant.harmonizedSystemCode || undefined,
      measurement: measurement,
      requiresShipping: db_variant.physicalProduct,
      sku: db_variant.SKU,
      tracked: db_variant.trackQuantity,
    },
    inventoryPolicy: db_variant.continueSellingWhenOutOfStock
      ? "CONTINUE"
      : "DENY",
    mediaId: found_mediaId || undefined,
    optionValues: shopify_optionValues,
    price: db_variant.price.toFixed(2),
    taxable: db_variant.chargeTaxes,
  }

I want to set an available quantity of 999 to each variant (in inventoryItem).
I was previously able to set it with the REST API of Shopify without any inventory location id.
Is this possible with GraphQL without the inventory location id, which needs the "read_locations" and "read_inventory" scopes?

No you can't assign inventory to a variant without using location. It's clearly marked as required in the doc. You can see here: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2024-07/mutations/productVariantsBulkCreate#argument-variants

Also I believe you won't be able to assign inventory quantitites to a variant in rest either. It's already deprecated and won't be available after 2025-01. See the two important marked notices at the top of this link: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2024-07/resources/product-variant#post-products-product-id-variants
